# @JsonIdentityInfo Stop serialization after first occurrence

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson

I have two entities as such:

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(
      generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, 
      property = "numeroOfferta")
@Entity
@Table(name=DatabaseConstants.TABELLA_OFFERTE)
public class Offerta {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private BigInteger numeroOfferta;

@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
private Cliente cliente;

private Double importoOfferta;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "offerta")
private Set<Ordine> ordini;
```

And:

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(
      generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, 
      property = "id")
@Entity
@Table(name=DatabaseConstants.TABELLA_ORDINI)
public class Ordine {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private BigInteger id;

private String numeroOrdine;

@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
private Offerta offerta;

private String stato;

@OneToOne(fetch= FetchType.EAGER)
private Binder binder;
```

Where exist a many-to-one relationship between the ORDINE and OFFERTA objects (more ORDINE to one OFFERTA).
When the entities are serialized in JSON it appears that if there is more than one ORDINE, only the first one is retreived completely, while the others appear only as their ID.

What I need is to serialize the ORDINE and its OFFERTA, without going back to ORDINE.

Is the use of @JsonIdentityInfo correct? 
Can anyone provide an explanation of the behavior described?